# Is it possible to create a proxy as a browser plugin?

Tags: http, proxy, reverse-proxy, browser-plugin

I have a website application where the users will perform tasks that will send request to other servers.

I wish those request to be performed through the users own IP and am therefore looking for a way to solve this issue, eg make sure that it is not my servers ip that are visible to the other servers.

One way of solving this would be that the user installed a browser plugin that serves as a proxy server, as the middle hand between the applications request and the other server.

Is this possible to do or will I stumble into hidden security blocks? Where would I begin to check for solutions?

Comment: Sounds like you are crafting a tool for fishing :-)

Comment: No, we are good guys don't you worry :)

Comment: Then why do you try to hide your address ?

Comment: It's rather the other way around. We are trying to show the end user's ip for the external server. Without a proxy it will be like we are hiding the users address.

Comment: You don't need a proxy for that. You just make the call to the remote server using ajax inside the client and the request will originate from the clients ip address. It has nothing to do with your server that delivered the web page.